# CATIA CAA folder structure

Tags: catia, caa

I am new to Catia CAA development, when we create a project in Visual studio. Folder is created with Cnext, Identity card, Private/Public/Protected interfaces. Can anyone explain what all these folders actually are? Thanks for any response

Answer (score 3):

When we create Framework in any CAA project few folder created automatically. These are - `CNext`, `IdentityCard`, `PrivateInterfaces`, `ProtectedInterfaces`, `PublicInterfaces` will be created. Following are the description of these folders:

**CNext**- In this folder, we have a folder named code which contains dictionary file in which we have a component name followed by interface name followed by module name having prefix lib.
Another folder is resources which contain.NLS, .Rsc, .bmp files

**IdentityCard**- It contains framework dependencies or you can say it supplies a list of prerequisite components for the framework.

PrivateInterfaces, ProtectedInterfaces, PublicInterfaces - In these folders header files of the Interfaces are put on the basis of their scope. These folders are actually used to create newly created interfaces, so its user's choice where he/she wants to put that interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

CAA Workspace contains frameworks. Frameworks contain modules. Modules contain Add-ins. Modules contain the IMakeFile

Modules create DLL extensions files. IMakeFile contains the modules used in the current module.

Public interfaces : These interfaces can be accessed across the whole framework or application

Private interfaces : These interfaces can be accessed within the framework

Protected interfaces : These interfaces are accessed within the workspace

Identity Card : Defines the prerequisite frameworks to be used in current framework. Adds the framework dependencies.

Resource files : 
1. MsgCatalog : .NIs file for messages/strings
2. MsgCatalog : .Rsc file for icon/images

Dico file : Details of interface and it's implementation (interface name and it's corresponding class/module name)

Answer (score 1):

Client code that will use CAA APIs should be have a specific structure. Project workspace (main project folder) contains one or many Frameworks (FWs). Each FW can have

- IdentityCard : dependencies described in the Identity card of the FW
- PublicInterfaces : Public interfaces offered by the FW
- CNEXT: Folder describing component names and interfaces implemented on them

Each FW can contain one or many modules (XXX.m). Each module can have:

- PrivateInterfaces (local header files)
- src : Source code (.cpp files)

Please refer to official guides :
https://www.3ds.com/support/documentation/developers-guides/